# anchor link not working bootstrap jscript

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I used a jquery plugin for my site to design a vertical side menu. The logout anchor link in the top navigation bar and a testing link in the menu  are not working. I am new to jquery and I found that the trick lies in the last part of jquery in the html file. But could not find the reason. Please explain the jquery and how to make the link work.

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

  <!-- FontAwesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Twitter Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-vertical-menu.css">

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <p class="navbar-text"><b style = "color:white">tnceo.com</b></p>
      <p class="navbar-text" style = "color:white">Welcome</p>
      <?php
echo '<p class="navbar-text" style = "color:black;background-color:orange;">'.$vsname.'</p>';
?>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a style = "font-weight:bold;color:yellow;" href="http://www.google.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Logout</b></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      </nav>

<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 affix-content">
<div class="container">
</div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-vertical-left">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href = "backup.html">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-star"></i> 
          <span>Menu 1</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href>
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-font"></i> 
          <span>Menu 2 </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href>
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-rocket"></i> 
          <span>Menu 3</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href>
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-cog"></i> 
          <span>Menu 4</span>
        </a>
      </li>
       </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 affix-content">
    <div class="page-header">
    <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Please read the instructions Carefully</h3>
    <h6>Use the administration menu on the left side</h6>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-primary">

        <!-- Default panel contents -->

        <div class="panel-heading">Basic Details</div>

        <div class="panel-body">

            <p>For any Changes in the following Basic details call the concerned DEO Office</p>

        </div>

        <!-- List group -->

        <div class="list-group">
   <?php
   echo '<li class="list-group-item">Revenue Code<span class="badge">'.$vrev.'</span></li>';

   echo '<li class="list-group-item">District Code<span class="badge">'.$vdist.'</span></li>';

   echo '<li class="list-group-item">School Name<span class="badge">'.$vsname.'</span></li>';

   echo '<li class="list-group-item">District Name<span class="badge">'.$vdname.'</span></li>';
   echo '<li class="list-group-item">School Status<span class="badge">'.$vstatus.'</span></li>';?>
   </div>
 </div>


<p>Instruction 1</p>
<p>Instruction 1</p>
<p>Instruction 1</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('a').click(function(event) {
        $('a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        event.preventDefault();
      })
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle for this

Comment: When I removed the script part in the last the link worked. I want to know the reason for adding the script and the function of the script. Thanks

Comment: I used a plugin from jquery plugin site and I now removing the last script part the link in the logout is working. Why such a script was given in the vertical menu plugin in the jquery site. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Explaining line by line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // Executin everything on DOM Ready
      $('a').click(function(event) { // Event to trigger on the click of a tag
        $('a').removeClass('selected'); // Remove selected class from all the a tags.
        $(this).addClass('selected'); // Add selected class to the clicked a tag, this will do some styling to highlight the clicked one.
        event.preventDefault(); // Stopping the link to open, as preventDefault(); removes the default behaviour.
      })
});
```

`event.preventDefault();` is the line which is stopping the link to open, remove it, the reason is explained in the code comment.

And, you don't need this code anyway, as you are linking to different page, this will be helpful and needed if you doing some client side scripting on the click of `a` tag instead of opening a new tag. So you can remove it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you sir I really appreciate your help

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of other commands in the jquery and the need if possible thanks